# Using list comprehension in Python to do something similar to zip()?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I'm a Python newbie and one of the things I am trying to do is wrap my head around list comprehension.  I can see that it's a pretty powerful feature that's worth learning.

```
cities = ['Chicago', 'Detroit', 'Atlanta']
airports = ['ORD', 'DTW', 'ATL']

print zip(cities,airports)
[('Chicago', 'ORD'), ('Detroit', 'DTW'), ('Atlanta', 'ATL')]
```

How do I use list comprehension so I can get the results as a series of lists within a list, rather than a series of tuples within a list?

```
[['Chicago', 'ORD'], ['Detroit', 'DTW'], ['Atlanta', 'ATL']]
```

(I realize that dictionaries would probably be more appropriate in this situation, but I'm just trying to understand lists a bit better). Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Something like this:

```
[[c, a] for c, a in zip(cities, airports)]
```

Alternately, the `list` constructor can convert tuples to lists:

```
[list(x) for x in zip(cities, airports)]
```

Or, the `map` function is slightly less verbose in this case:

```
map(list, zip(cities, airports))
```

Answer (score 8):

If you wanted to do it without using zip at all, you would have to do something like this:

```
[ [cities[i],airports[i]] for i in xrange(min(len(cities), len(airports))) ]
```

but there is no reason to do that other than an intellectual exercise.

Using `map(list, zip(cities, airports))` is shorter, simpler and will almost certainly run faster.

Comment: On the other hand, using a list comprehension and a zip together is just as short, and to me at least, even simpler. Do you happen to know how it's performance would compare with map?

Answer (score 5):

A list comprehension, without some help from `zip`, `map`, or `itertools`, cannot institute a "parallel loop" on multiple sequences -- only simple loops on one sequence, or "nested" loops on multiple ones.

Answer (score 3):

This takes `zip`'s output and converts all tuples to lists:

```
map(list, zip(cities, airports))
```

As for the performance of each:

```
$ python -m timeit -c '[ [a, b] for a, b in zip(xrange(100), xrange(100)) ]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 68.3 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -c 'map(list, zip(xrange(100), xrange(100)))'
10000 loops, best of 3: 75.4 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit -c '[ list(x) for x in zip(range(100), range(100)) ]'
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.9 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible to use `enumerate`, as well:

```
[[y,airports[x]] for x,y in enumerate(cities)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use list comprehension, and create a variable as a dictionary here is a decent way to do it:

```
newvariable = {key: value for key, value in zip(cities,airports)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to combine two lists,however in the real world you should prefer builtin functions (zip()) to complex flow statements.

```
zip_alternative=[ (cities[x],airports[y]) for x  in range(len(cities)) for y  in range(len(airports)) if x==y ]
```