# how to make a relation between two lists of number in python

Tags: python, list, relation, sublist

The specific question is like this:

I have `two lists`, namely:

```
lst1 = [1,2,5,6,7];
lst2 = [11,12,13,14,15];
```

I would like to build a relation of those lists to match with the corresponding number of the other list, like `1-11,5-13,7-15...`and if I input`[1,5,7]`, then it will automatically generate`[11,13,15]`. I'm new to python so I don't know if it is doable or could someone give me some advise or ideas, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create a dictionary with the elements of the first list as keys and the elements of the second list as values:

```
lst1 = [1,2,5,6,7]
lst2 = [11,12,13,14,15]

dct = dict(zip(lst1, lst2))
print(dct)  # {1: 11, 2: 12, 5: 13, 6: 14, 7: 15}
print(dct[1], dct[5], dct[7])  # 11 13 15
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "relation" you mean a 1-to-1 mapping, then perhaps you should take a look at [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). And if your lists (`lst1`, `lst2`) always have same length and order of mapping, you probably don't need a dictionary mapping, just use indexing correctly, along with the [`index` method for lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Answer (score 0):

first **zip** both list then use **list compression** over the output of list with if the condition

```
>>> lst1 = [1,2,5,6,7]

>>> lst2 = [11,12,13,14,15]

>>> input_lst = [1,2,5]

>>> [d for c,d in zip(lst1,lst2) if c in input_lst]      # first method Zip

>>> [lst2[lst1.index(v)] for v in (lst1) if v in input_lst]  # second mehod using index
```

**Output**

```
[11, 12, 13]
```

for detail [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169623/using-list-comprehension-in-python-to-do-something-similar-to-zip)

Answer (score 0):

`dict(zip(lst1, lst2))` will be okay.

```
container = dict(zip(lst1, lst2))

print(container[1], container[5], container[7])
```